# Is there a timeout option for remote access to PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, pgadmin, connectivity

I'm working *via* pgAdmin III on a remote PostgreSQL database. After a not so long period (say 10-15 min.) without doing anything in pgAdmin, the connection automatically expires. I therefore have a error message asking if I want to re-connect. This takes about 10 sec. and the database structure collapses, so I have to re-open the schemas I had open before.

Is there a way to change a timeout parameter somewhere so prevent the connection to expire for a longer period of time?

Answer (score 9):

A PostgreSQL server connection dropping after 10-15 minutes is almost certainly being caused by a state-tracking firewall (possibly using Network Address Translation (NAT)) between the client and the server. Many such firewalls have default timeouts of 15 minutes (900 seconds).

The three server-side parameters, `tcp_keepalives_idle`, `tcp_keepalives_interval`, `tcp_keepalives_count` are designed to help in these situations. See the documentation located here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-TCP-KEEPALIVES-IDLE

There are also client-side parameters for this: `keepalives`, `keepalives_idle`, `keepalives_interval`, `keepalives_count`, which you can set on connection. See the documentation located here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-KEEPALIVES

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64754/discussion-on-answer-by-colin-t-hart-is-there-a-timeout-option-for-remote-acces).

Comment: In case of Docker Swarm there is a `sysctls:` property of a service's configuration for which one can set e.g. `- net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=600`. This should work since compose file version `3.2`.